# Sorting a list of strings

Tags: java, list, sorting

I was handed this assignment:

> Complete the function void sort(List l) that sorts a list l that contains the strings
>   "one","two","three","four" (although not necessarily in that order). You should declare a Comparator, and use this with the Collections.sort function. The comparator should use the comp function described above. The list l will be altered when it is sorted.

and the code I have already writen is this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CW3 {

    private static HashMap < String, Integer > map = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();

    public CW3() {
        map.put("one", 1);
        map.put("two", 2);
        map.put("three", 3);
        map.put("four", 4);

        List listB = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new CW3().comp("one", "two"));
        System.out.println(new CW3().comp("two", "one"));
        System.out.println(new CW3().comp("one", "one"));
    }

    int comp(String s1, String s2) {
        int i1 = map.get(s1);
        int i2 = map.get(s2);
        return (i1 < i2 ? -1 : (i1 == i2 ? 0 : 1));
    }

    void sort(List l) {
        Comparator c = new Comparator() {

            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return 0; // FIXME change this so it calls comp
            }
        };
        // now sort l using the comparator c
        // FIXME complete this line
    }
```

Any ideas where to start? it says list so I would have to create a list but then how would I sort them?

Comment: In which order should the sorted list be? The task does not define that.

Comment: That is exaccctttlyyy what I am confused with..

Comment: One issue is that you're not explicitly declaring a comparator. You're just writing a method that does the compare logic

Comment: `comp` is already defined. All you need is to call it.  This is a very simple assignment: just follow `FIXME` instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to define the `compare` method. It should take two objects `o1` and `o2` as parameters and return

- `-1` when `o1 < o2`
- `0` when `o1 == o2`
- `1` when  `o1 > o2`

Your `Comparator` uses this method as a basis to decide the order of the elements. Then you sort the list `l` by calling `Collections.sort(l, c)`, where `c` is the `Comparator` you have defined.

Comment: Where would the objects come from? its pretty simple but im so confused

Comment: It doesn't matter where do they come from. You just define the `compare` method and `Comparator` *knows* how to use it. Similarly, when you have defined the `Comparator`, you call the `sort` method and it already implements a sorting algorithm, you only need to supply the `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below compar method

```
public class StepComparator implements Comparator<Step>{

@Override
public int compare(String so1, String s2) {

    if(map.get(s1)>map.get(s2)) return 1;

    return -1;
}

}
```

then you use this to sort them

```
StepComparator  comparator = new  StepComparator();
Collections.sort(list,comparator);
```